# ArcGIS Pro Unique Values with Domains Does not Display Correct Number of Classes

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, classification, domains, unique-value

Update 10/4/2022: A bug has been logged with esri.

This post may be overkill, but I'd like to see if anyone else has run into this and if they have a fix.

I'm trying to get ArcGIS Pro (2.9.2) to symbolize linework where three fields use a domain (0=false, 1=true), but also uses null values. This wasn't an issue in ArcMap. In the feature class the values are automatically `<Null>` until the user changes it. The user doesn't always set fields to False (0), rather they leave those as `<Null>`, so I have to make sure to include Null values with the symbology. There should be a total of 15 combinations based on how we symbolize the data. However, I can only get ArcGIS Pro to symbolize on 7 of them.

ArcGIS Pro combinations it does symbolize on (screenshot below): (StackExchange is displaying the table correctly until I post, so here's a screenshot of it displaying correctly)

[image: ArcGIS Pro Classifications]

Here's an example of the combinations needed (Same issue as the table above, here's a screenshot):

[image: Correct Combination of classes]

Using the green + for Adding Unlisted Values only works if there isn't a `<Null>` value. I'm assuming this is because ArcGIS Pro does not allow you (as far as I know) to type in `<Null>` as a value.

What I have tried:

1. Creating new fields with new domains in same feature class (returns same result)
2. Creating new file geodatabase with new feature class, domains, and fields. Drew in linework by hand (returns same result)
3. Loading in symbology from ArcMap (Symbolizes correctly, but count values are off (not an issue for me, but may be for someone else))
4. Using False in place of `<Null>` (works, but brings about other issues where users utilize false for other means)

ArcMap's correct classification and counts:
[image: ArcMap Correct Symbology and Counts]

Symbology classes in ArcGIS Pro - both how it loads and how it should display:

[image: Symbology classes in ArcGIS Pro both how it loads and how it should look]

Map view in ArcGIS Pro of how it loads in vs. how it should display:
[image: Map view of how it loads in vs. how it should look]

Comment: Not an answer per se, but changing any of the Null values to either false or just a third option (-1 for example), ArcGIS Pro is able to add all classes. While this isn’t ideal, it appears to be the only fix. My guess is that Pro has an issue looping through nulls.

Comment: Same problem.  So sick of ESRI's verminware domain implementation, wasted so much time with its endless garbage.